# How this simplification works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a real basic question. I was reading a book and it did the following simplification:

$$\frac{2}{n(n -1)} = \binom{n}{2}^{-1}$$

But I really did not understand how this simplification works. How the first value of this expression transformed into the second? I mean, what is the real meaning of the second expression?

Comment: The meaning of the second expression os $\dfrac{1}{\binom{n}{2}}$. You show it by inverting both sides, and apply the definition of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom nk$ is defined to be
$$
\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{1\cdot2\cdots k},
$$
for $n$ and $k$ natural numbers with $0\leq k\leq n$. In particular,
$$
\binom n2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.
$$
Taking the reciprocal of both sides of this equation (i.e., applying the power function $x^{-1}$) gives that
$$
\binom n2^{-1} = \frac{2}{n(n-1)},
$$
since you can take the reciprocal of a fraction by just flipping it.

Answer (score 0):

you only have to see te definition of $\binom{n}{2}$ and use that $n!=(n-1)!n$ so 
 $$\binom{n}{2} =\dfrac{(n-2)!(n-1)n}{(n-2)!2}$$ then doing the simplification you get the answer.

Comment: Type \binom{n}{k} in math mode to produce the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$.